# PHP: Can include a file that file_exists() says doesn't exist

Tags: php, file, path, include, require

In my script, I set the include path (so another part of the application can include files too), check that a file exists, and include it.

However, after I set the include path, `file_exists()` reports that the file does not exist, yet I can still include the same file.

```
<?php
  $include_path = realpath('path/to/some/directory');
  if(!is_string($include_path) || !is_dir($include_path))
  {
    return false;
  }
  set_include_path(
    implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
      $include_path,
      get_include_path()
    ))
  );
  // Bootstrap file is located at: "path/to/some/directory/bootstrap.php".
  $bootstrap = 'bootstrap.php';

  // Returns "bool(true)".
  var_dump(file_exists($include_path . '/' . $bootstrap));
  // Returns "bool(false)".
  var_dump(file_exists($bootstrap));

  // This led me to believe that the include path was not being set properly.
  // But it is. The next thing is what puzzles me.

  require_once $bootstrap;
  // Not only are there no errors, but the file is included successfully!
```

I can edit the include path and include files without providing the absolute filepath, but I cannot check whether they exist or not. This is really annoying as every time a file that does not exist is called, my application results in a fatal error, or at best a warning (using `include_once()`).

Turning errors and warnings off is not an option, unfortunately.

Can anyone explain what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_exists` does nothing more than say whether a file exists (and the script is allowed to know it exists), resolving the path relative to the cwd.   It does not care about the include path.

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought that was the most likely case, but couldn't find any mention of it in the PHP Manual. Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Here is the Simplest way to implement this

```
$file_name = //Pass File name 
if ( file_exists($file_name) )
            {
                echo "Exist";
            }
        else
            {
                echo "Not Exist";
            }
```