# PHP: include and file_exists scope

Tags: php, include, file-exists

I have a following directory structure:
 one folder "class" with "Test.php" and "conf.php" in it and one "index.php" file in the root:

```
/
index.php
class
   Test.php
   conf.php
```

The content of Test.php is:

```
<?php
class Test {

  public function __construct(){
    var_dump(file_exists("conf.php"));
    $conf = include("conf.php");
    echo $conf;
  }

}
```

"index.php" has following contents: (Just trying to instantiate a new Test class)

```
<?php
include "class/Test.php";
$Test = new Test();
```

And the file "conf.php" contains only this:

```
<?php
return "Included file";
```

After running this code I see the following output:

```
bool false
"Included file"
```

As you can see the "Test" object can include its local "conf.php" file and show its output,
but file_exists() doesn't see nothing. I don't understand why.
Maybe it is a php bug?

file_exists() returns "true" if I place the "conf.php" into the root (together with "index.php"). It seems that include is using the scope of the "Test.php" and "file_exists()" is using the scope of the file where the Test object were created (in the root in my case). What is the correct behavior?

(Using PHP 5.5.7 Fast-CGI)

Comment: When you call `file_exists()` without a full path, it checks from the location of the main script, not the location of the script that contains the function call. So if you include `Test.php` from `index.php`, the `file_exists()` is looking for `conf.php` in the parent directory, where it doesn't exist.  You have to think about it like an include is pulling all the code into that script, so everything is relative to that location.  You can use `__DIR__` in an included file to get the path to the actual included file.

Comment: `include` and `require` make use of `include_path`, but `file_exists()` and other filesystem functions expect real file paths.  From the root, `conf.php` is not found as a relative path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Can include a file that file\_exists() says doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331067/php-can-include-a-file-that-file-exists-says-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
class Test {

  public function __construct(){
    var_dump(file_exists( __DIR__ . "/conf.php"));
    $conf = include( __DIR__ . "/conf.php");
    echo $conf;
  }

}
```

Using the magic constant `__DIR__` will return the absolute path to the script it is used, instead of the script that includes it, so any file name references will be to full path of the file, rather than just relative paths, which uses the primary running script's location.